# YAML - multiple lines

Tags: yaml

I have a yaml file, which has a key called, openingTimes:, and a string 'Monday - Friday - 8am - 8pm, Saturday - 8am - 2pm', like this in markup:

```
openingTimes: >
    'Monday - Friday - 8am - 8pm
     Saturday - 8am - 2pm'
```

I have tried using a YAML validator, to confirm the markup is correct, and it works fine, as a multiple line, in YAML. However, when I pasted the markup into my YAML file, it does not format the markup on the webpage correctly. It doesn't make the lines, multiple lines. I have used the pipe flag as well and this works correctly in the validator, but not in my YAML file.

What am doing wrong please? Thanks in advance for any help (I have gone through Stackoverflow on creating multiple lines in YAML), without success.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) describing what you're doing with the YAML and show what the expected output is and what the actual output is. We don't magically know what *webpage* you're referencing since you do not give any indication how that webpage comes into existence. What does „*make the lines multiple lines*“ mean? What's „*the pipe flag*“?

Comment: Hi, I have a HTML template, which has a property called {openingHours}. In the YAML file openingTimes property has a String as 'Monday - Friday - 8am - 8pm'. When I have formatted the String to reflect multiple lines of another line as 'Saturday 8am - 2pm'. The output I expect is:

Comment: In order for a newline to render in HTML, you need `<br>`.

Comment: Hi, I have a HTML template, which has a property called {openingHours}. In the YAML file openingTimes property has a String as 'Monday - Friday - 8am - 8pm'. When I have formatted the String to reflect multiple lines of another line as 'Saturday 8am - 2pm'. The output I expect is, on the 1st line, 'Monday - Friday - 8am - 8pm', and on the next line 'Saturday 8am - 2pm'. The output I am getting is both Strings are on the same line. I have tried to use the '>' and the '|', which tells YAML, this whole String should be formatted as multiple lines. Thanks

Comment: Nothing tells YAML that a string *should be formatted as multiple lines*. YAML is not an HTML formatter. You can use `|` to tell YAML that the data is to contain line breaks. However, inserting a line break into HTML source will not make HTML display a line break when rendered. The general solution is to add a `<br>` tag. There may be more specialized solutions depending on your environment which you tell us nothing about (e.g. what is your templating engine etc).